# cfldap bind and search

Tags: php, coldfusion, ldap

I am having an issue with something I've done in PHP a thousand times: binding on an LDAP group, then searching to see if the user is a member for authorization.

In PHP I would always write this like

```
<?
            $this->root_pw = "guid_password";
            $this->bind_dn = "group_guid";  

    $this->ldapconn = ldap_connect($this->server, $this->port); 
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($this->ldapconn, $this->bind_dn, $this->root_pw);
               $this->result = ldap_search($this->ldapconn,$this->base_dn, $filter);
                if( ldap_count_entries($this->ldapconn,$this->result) == 1 ) {                                  

                                        return true;
                                    } else {

                                        return false;
                                        }   
        }
?>
```

So if the user is not a member of the group GUID, the return is false.

However, doing the same thing in ColdFusion (or what I think is the same thing) will *always* return the user whether or not they are in the group.

```
<cfset var response=false />
            <!--- setting basic attributes --->
            <cfset LDAP_root = "o=someplace">
            <cfset LDAP_server = "server.com">
            <cfset LDAP_port = "636">

            <!--- Group DN and password--->
            <cfset LDAP_username = "group_guid">
            <cfset LDAP_password = 'guid_password'>
            <cfset userfilter =
                "uid=#lcase(arguments.userName)#">

     <cfldap action="query"
                    name="auth"
                    attributes="uid, cn, mail"
                    referral="yes"
                    start="#LDAP_root#"
                    scope="SUBTREE"
                    server="#LDAP_server#"
                    port="#LDAP_port#"
                    filter="#userfilter#"
                    username="#LDAP_username#"
                    password="#LDAP_password#"
                    secure = "CFSSL_BASIC"


                > 
<cfif auth.recordCount gt 0>
             <cfset response = true />

        </cfif>
```

Any help is *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: what does auth.recordcount return?

Comment: 1 if the user exists, 0 if they dont, whether theyre a member of the group is not being filtered. It should return 1 if they exist and theyre a member

Comment: It looks like that ldap query will only return if the user exists.  It doesn't look like it is checking if they are a member of a particular group.

Comment: I was thinking.   Maybe a filter like so could do it.

(&(objectClass=user)(uid=yourUserName)(memberof=full DN of group))

I don't know which LDAP server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and get the variable from your query. Try doing somthing like

CFSET Session.group= "#auth.Group#"

with auth.group is your query name and ldapt attribute.

I use an cfldap connection. Then store a name in a session variable with CFSET Session.this_FName= "#Results.GivenName#" (Results is the name of my query).  Then after uses if #Session.this_FName# neq "Adam" then ...